# How do you say "...is worth the wait" in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, translation

I kind of understand the phrase やった甲斐があった from a post by Sjiveru, but how do you express the notion that doing something now or in the future is worth it? For example, how would you say "The wait is long, but it is worth it because the udon is so delicious"? I made the sentence 「待つのはながいですが、うどんはすごくおいしいから、甲斐があります」, but I am not sure if this makes any sense. Should I say instead at the end of the sentence「待つのは甲斐があります」, or should I change the entire sentence instead?

Comment: I would reorder the phrases so that 待つ and 甲斐 would be closer. It'd sound more natural. うどんはすごく美味しいので、待つのは長いですがその甲斐があります。More commonly あのうどん屋は待つ甲斐がある.  I can imagine the scene of a line forming in front of the udon place, and drooling for tasty udon. haha.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the phrase 甲斐がある, the correct way of combining it with 待つ is 待った甲斐があった, just like やった甲斐があった, which is the verb やる.

However, your sentence `待つのはながいですが、うどんはすごくおいしいから、甲斐があります` is also correct, not modifying 甲斐 with a verb, since what 甲斐 you're talking about is already clear from context.

`待つのは甲斐があります` would be a general statement, like `the action of waiting would be worthwhile`, something you could say before the waiting starts to tell people it will be worth it. If it's something you say afterwards, then it's 待った甲斐があった（ありました） where you use the past tense.

In addition, I also suggest looking up the phrase 割に合う, which also means "(a hard work) paying off". Your waiting paid off, so

> 待つ時間は長いんだけど、うどんがめっちゃ美味しくて、本当に**割にあった**んだ！

Answer (score 1):

The formula is [verb]甲斐がある or [verb]甲斐があった and the verb's tense should match that of ある/あった, as long as you are trying to translate simple cases of English tenses, I think. のは is unnecessary.

- やった甲斐があった (was worth doing / one-time thing)
- やる甲斐がある (is worth doing, will be worth doing)
- 待った甲斐があった (was worth the wait / one-time thing)
- 待つ甲斐がある (is worth the wait, will be worth the wait)

The other variations are a bit tricky to explain. I think it involves how grammatical aspects between two verbs in a sentence work in general, and they are... complicated. I don't think I can cover everything about aspects here. (I'm sure good textbooks explain them better than I could.) Here are typical interpretations under the given context I can think of right know.

- 待った甲斐がある - the waiting is completed, and the payoff is not. I don't know how to phrase it succinctly in English using "worth -ing".
- 待つ甲斐があった - both the waiting and the payoff happened repeatedly.
- 待っている甲斐がある - the waiting is being done (not completed).
- 待っている甲斐があった - the waiting is repeatedly done, and the payoff is a one-time thing. (This doesn't make much sense in the case of "waiting". Something like 練習している would make more sense.)
- 待っていた甲斐があった - similar to 待った甲斐があった, but emphasis on the continuity (or the length) of the waiting
- 待っていた甲斐がある - similar to 待った甲斐がある, but emphasis on the continuity (or the length) of the waiting

Comment: As written, your answer strongly implies that 待つ甲斐があった would be an incorrect or (at least unusual) way to translate "was worth waiting for" or "was worth the wait." This surprises me, and I wonder if perhaps you could edit your answer to clarify whether this is really what you mean, and if so, why.

Comment: Good point. I have written more about 待つ甲斐があった and other variations.